# Which one is better for getting the last row of my table with linq to nhibernate?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Which one is better for getting the last row of my table with linq to nhibernate? Why?

```
    internal Bill GetLastBill()
    {
        var q = from b in session.Linq<Bill>()
                select b;

        return q.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();
    }
```

OR

```
    internal Bill GetLastBill()
    {
        long maxId = session.Linq<Bill>().Max(i => i.Id);

        var q = from b in session.Linq<Bill>()
                where b.Id == maxId
                select b;

        return q.First();
    }
```

Comment: Is `session.Linq<Bill>()` sorted in any fashion?

Comment: You should a database profiler (or use NHProf) to see the generated query. They could both be using the same query. The only way to be sure is to profile it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
return session.Linq<Bill>().Last();
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx)

Comment: What is the generated sql query for this linq query?

Comment: Not working "The LastResultOperator result operator is not current supported"

Answer (score 3):

Of your two choices the first options is better because it does 1 query.   Second option will execute 2 queries.